# Error cURL con PHP

Tags: php, curl

Tengo un **PHP** que hace peticiones **cURL** a una URL y a veces al recibir datos recibo lo siguiente:

307 Temporary Redirect
307 Temporary Redirect
nginx

El **PHP** con **cURL** es el siguiente:

```
$fp=fopen("../datosAPI/bitcoin.json", "w");
// Se crea un manejador CURL
$ch=curl_init();
// Se establece la URL y algunas opciones
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/btc-usd");
//determina si descargamos las cabeceras del servidor [0-No mostramos|1-mostramos]
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
//determina si mostramos el resultado en el nevagador [0-mostramos|1-NO mostramos]
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
//determina donde guardar el fichero
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
// Se obtiene la URL indicada
curl_exec($ch);
// Se cierra el recurso CURL y se liberan los recursos del sistema
curl_close($ch);
//se cierra el manejador de ficheros
fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 0):

El error indica que hay una redirección temporal, la "nueva url" donde hacer la petición vendrá en un header `location`.
Para que `cURL` reintente con la nueva location hay que especificarle antes del `curl_exec`:

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

para saber cual fue la redireción poner antes del `curl_close`

```
 $redirectURL = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL );
```

Dependiendo de que tan elocuente sea esta nueva url podes llegar a saber que condición hace que se produzca el redirect (hace falta login, muchas conexiones, reenviar credenciales, etc...) por lo general es algo que se puede resolver con una nueva petición o siguiendo la nueva url que te da el servidor.

referencia: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28458522/1423096

**Nota** la diferencia entre un 302, 303 y 307 es que en este último hay que repetir/seguir la petición usando el mismo método HTTP (si era GET seguir con GET, si fue un POST seguir con POST)